# different value types in javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, alert

In strictly native JS, is there a way to display a string and variable in one alert window (or other window)? For now, let's ignore fancy things like jQuery, Vue, Node, etc.

```
var testNumber = prompt("Enter a number. Let us see how many even numbers 
are therein.");  
var countEvens = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= testNumber; i++) { 
    if (i % 2 === 0){
    countEvens++;
  }
}
alert("There are " countEvens " even numbers in" testNumber);
```

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are one way, ES6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you can. just ad `+` operator to concatenate. `alert("There are " +countEvens +"even numbers in"+testNumber);`

```js
var testNumber = prompt("Enter a number. Let us see how many even numbers are therein.");  
var countEvens = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= testNumber; i++) { 
    if (i % 2 === 0){
    countEvens++;
  }
}
alert("There are " +countEvens +" even numbers in" +testNumber);
```

Comment: I totally forgot about concatenation.
Thank you for not saying rude things. I feel like I deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

In strictly native JS, there is no `alert` or any other mechanism for showing output. JS depends on the host environment to provide that sort of API.

A web browser's `alert` method will pay attention only to the first argument, which it converts to a string if it isn't one already.

If you want to construct your string from multiple variables and literals you can use concatenation:

```
alert("There are " + countEvens + " even numbers in " + testNumber);
```

or template strings:

```
alert(`There are ${countEvens} even numbers in ${testNumber}`);
```